# When should I create another publication, performance-wise?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I have one publication with 10 fields for my first template.

I have another template where I need only 5 fields of the same publication. Since user can access both, depending on the loaded template, security is out of concern.

**The question**:

*Performance-wise, should I make another publication with only the 5 fields I need, or should I rely on my first publication?*

I expect it to be a trade-off between:

1. the amount of data sent
2. the server side load (each of these publications would use `cursor.observe()`)
3. the number of users currently subscribing (the mergeBox load)

Another solution could be to create 2 publication: the basic with 5 field and another one with the 5 other fields. In my first template, I subscribe to both, in the second I subscribe to the first only.

I understand the theory, but I can't infer from it what is the best approach. I expect there are good practices in these kind of cases.

All could be equivalent too, and it would make it an unnecessary micro-optimization (and that would answer my question).

Thanks!

Comment: You may as well make another publication for the 5 field set. Unless the data is sent before hand (sent, then the user chooses 10 or 5) or you want the users to change on the fly - less data transfer is more better. It's a "micro-optimization", you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you definitely have the right thought process and it's hard to say if I should optimize now or later. I would suggest doing it if it's not taking very much time.

For the case where you have a lot of users, you definitely want your app to track the minimal amount of database fields possible. I think your approach with two subscriptions is good. One thing I would suggest is reducing the amount of subscriptions for the first template by having a publication that has all 10 fields, so it doesn't have to subscribe twice.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. It is not a big deal to do it so I will. I validate your answer since it makes sense (same as @below9k). It would make a great article to have compared data about each case, I probably secretly wished to see someone show up with it. Too bad SO is not Santa Claus :)